# Have to click six or seven times before response

Tags: mouse

I'm having a problem with my mouse. Sometimes when I want to click the menu button in the top left corner (I have Mate), I have to click six or seven times before it responds. I already tried a different mouse. Sometimes it does respond but as I said sometimes it takes a lot more clicks than would be sensible.

It does it in other parts of the screen as well by the way, sometimes just another window. Sometimes 3 or 2 clicks. Sometimes especially when it's the menu button it's 6 or 7 times.

It's a weird thing and it makes me wonder what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.  (you mention trying another mouse, but not if it was the same, or different, better or worse on average etc)

Comment: I have the 18.04.4 LTS release (Bionic Beaver). Mate 1.20.1. It was a different mouse and it stayed the same didn't make any difference. But now it got worse, after trying out a different color setting I couldn't click the menu button at all anymore and had to reinstall operating system for it to work again. It seemed to be gone for a moment with the new install but I had to set up some more things like for audio to work for example and it started with the 7'ish clicks again. It does work though after some clicks and is more responsive than when I installed a new color. I have dual boot btw.